# How to start and stop NVDA screen reader reading text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, wai-aria, screen-readers

I am actually trying to stop NVDA screen reader before executing one typing text function and then again I want start it after finished typing function. So anyone knows how to do that using jQuer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. We can use aria-hidden attribute for this. Glad to found it myself.